# A list of Word 2007 Headings

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to quickly generate a list of all the headings used in a Word 2007 document?

I just want a print out of all the headings, I have a table of contents which only displays the first three levels but I have headings as far down as five levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, temporarily, add a second table of contents that includes all the heading levels (or by style, allowing more than one category of headings to be included) and the print it out, or copy the text.

Comment: Was hoping to find some basic reporting features to extract this sort of info. Aw well, this will do. Thanks